# std::set and delegated constructor, why is it necesary?

Tags: c++, constructor, set, c++14

I've seen, in `cppreference`, that the definition of the `std::set` constructor, and probably many other constructors, have changed from:

```
explicit set(const Compare& comp = Compare(), 
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

to

```
set() : set(Compare()) {}
explicit set(const Compare& comp, 
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

in C++14, which, as far as I know, are exactly equivalent definitions. What is the reason of that change?

Comment: Because it can now? I guess it allows the compiler to lay down a separate function for set::set() out of line. This removes the burden of default argument construction and destruction from the call sites.

Comment: The reason is that the default constructor is not explicit, what allows you to say `std::set<int> s = {};`, or `return {};`

Comment: @T.C. Why did your Mjolnir not kick in? Did you cast another vote beforehand?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I don't have the C++14 hammer, and added the C++ tag only after I noticed that :)